# What does one call the twisting of a proper name into a pejorative?

Tags: expressions, vocabulary, pejorative-language

For example, in politics one sees Obummer, John Boner, Mittens R-money

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "twisting". _Boycott_ and _Lynch_ are still the same names, spelled and pronounced the same way (though without capitals), even though they're pejoratives. The ones you cite are pretty dumb, and don't really need a special name, since each one is unhappy in its own unique way, like unhappy families.

Comment: The word _parody_ might be applicable.