# Is there a technical name for a play on words, such as "FaceCrook"?

Tags: puns

Is there a technical name for the play on words where someone would substitute a word for a similar one (or add a common word to the end of one) in order to express their opinion about the subject in question?

For example:

- Not being a fan of Facebook's privacy rules, and calling the site Face**crook** instead
- Feeling that people are too lazy to search before posting here, so calling this site "**Slack** Exchange"
- Calling a Didgeridoo a "Didgeridont" because you can't stand the sound it makes

The closest things I could find were a "sniglet" and a "protologism", but I'm not sure if they're it. Any thoughts?

Comment: I answered *pun* but then I noticed you tagged the question as pun, so I'm guessing that's not what you're looking for.

Comment: @RexYuan I wasn't sure what to tag it as, so I just picked "Pun" as it was closest. I had originally thought _Pun_, but felt it was too "generic" of a word and thought there was a more specific term. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: Possible, but I don't think so. However, all the examples I used in my answer would fit just as well in there.

Comment: related: [What does one call the twisting of a proper name into a pejorative?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/115701/what-does-one-call-the-twisting-of-a-proper-name-into-a-pejorative?lq=1); [“Tortoise” and “taught us”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/40662/tortoise-and-taught-us); [Is there a technical name for this kind of wordplay?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/226483/is-there-a-technical-name-for-this-kind-of-wordplay)

Comment: eggcorn vs. malapropism http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/125405/what-do-you-call-it-when-someone-misunderstands-a-homonym/125411#125411

Answer (score 2):

So, using the help of Google and some 45 minutes of research, I found that what you are looking for might be called an egg corn (eggcorn).

An egg corn or eggcorn is when you deliberately make a pun with an intended malapropism (all definitions will be at end of answer).

For example:

> Lord of the Fries

Lord of the Fries is the name of a chips (or fries for you Americans out there) shop, with a name being based off of "Lord of the Flies".

By changing "flies" to "fries", they are making a malapropism, albeit it being intended.

Another example of this is (while continuing with the fish and chips theme):

> The Codfather

This fish shop's name is a pun on the film "The Godfather".

Other examples are "Wok 'n' roll", "Pita Pan", and "Sew What?", being respectively similar to "Rock 'n' roll", "Peter Pan", and "So what?".

## Definitions

A pun is a word or phrase with usually two meanings, although it can be more. Puns are intended to be funny.
An egg corn (eggcorn) on the other hand, is a pun with an intended malapropism, yet it is not intended to be funny. Essentially, it just "happens".
A malapropism is when you incorrectly substitute a word in, which has a similar sound, yet entirely different meanings. A Freudian slip seems to have a similar meaning.

And that should be it. I hope this was of at least some help to answering your question.

Comment: I get that it's a pun and all, but why in the world does someone name their joint after Lord of the Flies? I already feel like getting my fries somewhere else.

Comment: Lol, I don't know. There's a Lord of the Wings chicken shop too.

Comment: No, *Facecrook* is not an example of an eggcorn. Eggcorns are genuine mistakes which occur when a person mishears or misunderstands a word. The word "eggcorn" is a misunderstanding of the term *acorn*, if a person had never heard or knew what an *acorn* was, they will find the closest most logical (for them) equivalent. Facecrook is instead a **deliberate** caricature or [**play on words**](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/play-on-words) of the term Facebook.  http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/54289/is-there-a-term-for-pejorative-parody-names-of-people-or-places

Comment: Well, it was the best I could find to help the asker of the question.